# $_.passwordLastset.AddDays(30) for each language/country

Tags: powershell

I am close of the end to finish my project but I am looking for some help .

How can I format the date for each language because `$_.passwordLastset.AddDays(30)` return like `Friday, July 27, 2018 2:44:14 PM` .
I would like `Vendredi 27 juillet a 14h44` for french people example .
I found formatdatetime but I can't found how to use it .
vendredi =day 
juillet =month

Thank you for you help .

Comment: Take a look at (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/08/25/use-culture-information-in-powershell-to-format-dates/)

Comment: thank you so much I found something  and I will try it
`$LocaleNL = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-NL") #Dutch (Netherlands) Locale
$LocaleEN = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US") #English (US) Locale
$LocaleFR = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR") #french local time

(Get-Date).adddays(90).tostring("dddd, yyyy-MM-dd",$LocaleNL) 
(Get-Date).adddays(90).tostring("dddd, yyyy-MM-dd",$LocaleEN)
(get-Date).AddDays(90).tostring("dddd, dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",$LocaleFR)`

Answer (score 3):

Rather than just passing the `[DateTime]` to the output (which leads to the default formatting in the current culture) explicitly format.

```
$frfr = new-object System.Globalization.CultureInfo 'fr-fr'
[datetime]::Now.ToString($frfr)
```

You can of course also pass a [format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) if you don't want that culture's default format

```
[datetime]::Now.ToString('F', $frfr)
```

Answer (score 0):

thank all ,with your help I found how to it and also I share usefull link https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/2comxz/how_to_adjust_the_datetime_readout_according_to/
I will try then give you a feelback

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Richard's answer - you can also use LCID's:

```
1030..1036 | % {
  $culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo($_)
  (Get-Date).ToString('F',$culture)
}

#output
27. juli 2018 16:01:45
Freitag, 27. Juli 2018 16:01:45
Παρασκευή, 27 Ιουλίου 2018 4:01:45 μμ
Friday, July 27, 2018 4:01:45 PM
viernes, 27 de julio de 2018 16:01:45
27. heinäkuuta 2018 16:01:45
vendredi 27 juillet 2018 16:01:45
```

Answer (score 0):

I will code this question by this .
I wrote a function who can you use for your script .

Function code ($code)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms912047(v=winembedded.10)
    {

```
$culture =[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo($code)
(get-date).ToString('F',$culture)

}

code 1079


Example of usage in my script .replace('$FULLNAME',$_.DisplayName).replace('$EXPIRE',(code 1079))
```

$expire in my email will be replaced by the full date .

I can confirm is perfectly fine .
that's so cool .

thank you everyone for your help ,that's great community .